# Is there a way to specify the output path of .coverage?

Tags: coverage.py

I'm looking for a way to specify the output path of the generated `.coverage` file. I've checked `coverage help` and did some research but still no luck so far. The reason is that I would like it to be specified into our tmp directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `.coveragerc` and specify the path for `.coverage` using the `data_file` attribute under the `[run]` section.

[This](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/config.html) is the link to the current documentation.

Comment: link no longer works. Please answer the question in a stand alone manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[run] data_file` setting (https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#run), or the `COVERAGE_FILE` environment variable (https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd.html#data-file).

Comment: The links are broken

Comment: Fixed.
I have nothing more to say than that, but there's a minimum comment length, so I guess I will just discuss that....